# Regex speed in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I've been previously working only with `bash` regular expressions, `grep`, `sed`, `awk` etc. After trying `Perl 6` `regexes` I've got an impression that they work slower than I would expect, but probably the reason is that I handle them incorrectly. 
I've made a simple test to compare similar operations in `Perl 6` and in `bash`. Here is the `Perl 6` code:

```perl6
my @array = "aaaaa" .. "fffff";
say +@array; # 7776 = 6 ** 5

my @search = <abcde cdeff fabcd>;

my token search {
    @search
}

my @new_array = @array.grep({/ <search> /});
say @new_array;
```

Then I printed `@array` into a file named `array` (with 7776 lines), made a file named `search` with 3 lines (`abcde`, `cdeff`, `fabcd`) and made a simple `grep` search.

```bash
$ grep -f search array
```

After both programs produced the same result, as expected, I measured the time they were working.

```bash
$ time perl6 search.p6
real    0m6,683s
user    0m6,724s
sys     0m0,044s
$ time grep -f search array
real    0m0,009s
user    0m0,008s
sys     0m0,000s
```

So, what am I doing wrong in my Perl 6 code?

**UPD:** If I pass the search tokens to `grep`, looping through the `@search` array, the program works much faster:

```perl6
my @array = "aaaaa" .. "fffff";
say +@array;

my @search = <abcde cdeff fabcd>;

for @search -> $token {
  say ~@array.grep({/$token/});
}
```

```bash
$ time perl6 search.p6
real    0m1,378s
user    0m1,400s
sys     0m0,052s
```

And if I define each search pattern manually, it works even faster:

```bash
my @array = "aaaaa" .. "fffff";
say +@array; # 7776 = 6 ** 5

say ~@array.grep({/abcde/});
say ~@array.grep({/cdeff/});
say ~@array.grep({/fabcd/});
```

```bash
$ time perl6 search.p6
real    0m0,587s
user    0m0,632s
sys     0m0,036s
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `grep`  command is much simpler than Perl 6's regular expressions, and it has had many more years to get optimized. It is also one of the areas that hasn't seen as much optimizing in Rakudo; partly because it is seen as being a difficult thing to work on.

---

For a more performant example, you could pre-compile the regex:

```perl6
my $search = "/@search.join('|')/".EVAL;
#  $search =  /abcde|cdeff|fabcd/;
say ~@array.grep($search);
```

That change causes it to run in about half a second.

If there is any chance of malicious data in `@search`, and you have to do this it may be safer to use:

```perl6
"/@search».Str».perl.join('|')/".EVAL
```

---

The compiler can't quite generate that optimized code for `/@search/` as `@search` could change after the regex gets compiled. What could happen is that the first time the regex is used it gets re-compiled into the better form, and then cache it as long as `@search` doesn't get modified.
(I think Perl 5 does something similar)

One important fact you have to keep in mind is that a regex in Perl 6 is just a method that is written in a domain specific sub-language.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanations! It works with `.join` very fast indeed (yet much slower than `gnu grep` in `bash`)! Could I please ask you to clarify the following? ① Am I right that the main waste of time is because the program checks the values of `@search` each time it wants to compare it with an element of @array? ② What does the `».` syntax mean and what type of malicious code should I be aware of? In my work, the keys for search may come from files with data, so maybe it would be nice to check them beforehand?

Comment: ③ Does the `regex` machine work faster in Perl 5, so can we hope that in future it will be faster in Perl 6? ④ I don't fully understand your last statement (about the sub-language), so could you please explain it? I feel that it's an important thing. ⑤ If I need to perform really heavy (with very large data or very many search keys) but simple `regex` operations, are there possibly other ways to optimize Perl 6's performance or I should rather use simple `bash` scripts for them?

Comment: @evb ① mostly yes ② `@foo».bar` is similar to `@foo.map(*.bar)`. ③regexes in Perl 5 are significantly different ④ In most languages a regex is a separate thing that gets compiled separately, in Perl 6 it is very much just code with a different syntax. ⑥ You could parallelize such operations to use as many CPU cores as you have. Also since as I said it is just code, and you can optimize code, yes there may be ways of writing a more optimized version.

Comment: Yet another question (should I post it as a separate Q with examples?) My search keys are frequently every possible (concatenated) combinations of atoms provided in `arrays`, so I wonder, whether it is possible in order to improve the performance to precompile a `regex`, which itself consists of several named `regexes`? Is it then possible to precompile the `TOP` `regex/token` in a grammar? (Of course I understand that if there are too many combinations, the result may not fit in memory)

Comment: You'd have much better performance still if you grepped with constant strings and eq: `say ~@array.grep({ $^a eq "abcde" or $^a eq "cdeff" or $^a eq "fabcd" })` takes only 0.24s (0.09s of which are startup and compilation)

Comment: @BradGilbert There happens to be an even better way: `my $search = any(@search)`. I've tested it and it works very quickly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927870/making-a-junction-out-of-an-array-with-string-values-in-perl-6/46928740#46928740

Comment: The drawback seems to be that "Junctions are meant to be used as matchers in boolean context; introspection of junctions is not supported". :(

Comment: @EugeneBarsky I'm curious if you found a way to use Junctions to increase speed for your purposes while working around the lack of support of introspection.

Comment: @raiph Only precompiling regexes, as Brad Gilbert proposed.