# Making a junction out of an array with string values in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Here's what I'm trying to do. It should be very simple, but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

```perl6
> my @search_keys = <bb cc dd>
[bb cc dd]
> my $search_junc = @search_keys.join('|')
bb|cc|dd
> "bb" eq $search_junc
False
```

Comment: There's no reason to expect a string to behave as if it were the equivalent Perl code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
my @search_keys = <bb cc dd>;
say "bb" eq any(@search_keys);     # any(True, False, False)
say so "bb" eq any(@search_keys);  # True
```

The `|` syntax is merely sugar for calling the `any()` function.  Just like `&` is syntactic sugar for the `all()` function.  They both return `Junction`s, which you can collapse with e.g. the `so` function.  Of course, if you're going to use it in a conditional, you don't need to collapse it yourself, the `Bool`ification of the condition will do that for you:

```
say "found" if "bb" eq any(@search_keys);
```

See also: https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction

EDIT (more than 2 years later):

If you are interested in the simple equivalence of the given object (`"bb"`) in the list (`<bb cc dd>`), you can also use set operators for that:

```
say "found" if "bb" (elem) @search_keys;  # found
```

Technically, this will do the comparison on the `.WHICH` of the given strings.  More importantly, this idiom will short-cut as soon as a match is found.  So since in your example `"bb"` is the first element in the array, it will only check that element.  And it won't need to build any additional objects, like a `Junction` (in the first solution) or a `Set` (in the second solution).