# Filtering elements of an array with elements of another array in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I want to filter elements of `@array` which begin with elements of `@search`:

```perl6
my @array = "aaaaa" .. "fffff";
my @search = "aaaa" .. "cccc";
.put for @array .grep: /^ @search /;
```

The problem is it takes 19 seconds. So, I ['precompile'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869857/7730888) the `regex` for `grep`, and the whole program looks like this:

```perl6
my @array = "aaaaa" .. "fffff";
my @search = "aaaa" .. "cccc";

my $search = "/@search.join('|')/".EVAL;

.put for @array .grep: * ~~ /^ <$search> /;
```

Now it takes 0.444s.

The question: is there a built-in Perl 6 method to do such things? Something like inserting a `junction` into a `regex`...

Comment: What do you mean by "works for"? Does it crash after that much time?

Comment: `.put for @array .grep: @search.any;`

Comment: @BradGilbert The output will be wrong. E.g. `faaaa` will be filtered, but shouldn't. The filtered elements should *begin* with strings from `@search`. (I.e. I'm looking for a solution with `regexes`)

Comment: @BradGilbert: you'd have to grep for `*.starts-with(@search.any)`

Comment: @Christoph Oh yes, that solves this particular case, that's my fault. :) Though I'm looking for something more general to merge strings into a `regex`.

Answer (score 4):

```
my @array = "aaaaa" .. "fffff";
my @search = "aaaa" .. "cccc";
my $join = @search.join('|');
my $rx = rx{ ^ <{$join}> };

@array.grep( * ~~ $rx ).map( *.put )
```

You need to create the join string separately of it will evaluate the array join for each match. But the basically gives you what you want without using EVAL.

Comment: Thanks! If I'm not mistaken, the function of `EVAL` is performed by the inner `{}`?

Comment: `<{ }>` in a regex evaluates the inner block and puts the string result into the regex. It means you don't use the potentially dangerous `EVAL` method.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to speed this up by assembling the regexes.

I am not sure how to do this using pure Perl *6* but [`Regexp::Assemble`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble) is a Perl *5* module that can do this for Perl *5* regexes. You can use Perl *5* modules in Perl *6* code by appending a `:from<Perl5>` (without a preceding space) to a `use` statement and then accessing its exported symbols (classes, objects, routines, etc.) as if it was a Perl *6* module:

```
use v6;

use Regexp::Assemble:from<Perl5>;

my @array = "aaaaa" .. "fffff";
my @search = "aaaa" .. "cccc";
my $ra = Regexp::Assemble.new;
$ra.add( @search );
$ra.anchor_string_begin(1);
.put for @array.grep({so($ra.match( $_ ))});
```

Comment: Thanks, an interesting solution. How could I install this Perl 5 module? And yet I wonder, whether there is a pure v6 way to do it...

Comment: @EugeneBarsky I use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/). Follow the instructions at the [GitHub page](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5) of `Inline::Perl5` and install a relocateable `perl`. Then install `cpanm` for `perlbrew`, using `perlbrew install-cpanm`, also see documentation on [metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-perlbrew/bin/perlbrew). Then install Perl 5 module `Regexp::Assemble` using `cpanm Regexp::Assemble`.. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of search, you can easily use [`index`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#routine_index)

```
say (@array X @search).grep( { defined($^a[0].index($^a[1])) } )
    .grep( { $^a[0].index($^a[1]) == 0 } );
```

This creates a list of Cs, and seeks the second element of the pair within the first; it returns only the list of those that appear in the first position. `defined` is needed because it will return `Nil` if it does not find it. It's not faster than your alternative above, but it's in the same ballpark, with 0.03 system time and ~ 0.30 seconds

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `.starts-with()` instead in this case? An I still don't understand why we cannot use only the second `.grep` — `Nil == 0` will give `False`, so those elements will be filtered out.

Comment: Nil is going to issue a warning. But `starts-with` makes sense.