# Can I modify a literal regex in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

Suppose we have a regular inflectional pattern, which cannot be split into segments. E.g. it can be infixation (adding some letters inside the word) or vowel change ('ablaut'). Consider an example from German.

```perl6
my @words = <Vater Garten Nagel>;
my $search = "/@words.join('|')/".EVAL;

"mein Vater" ~~ $search;                              
say $/;   # ｢Vater｣
```

All the three German words form plural by changing their 2nd letter 'a' to 'ä'. So 'Vater' → 'Väter', 'Garten' → 'Gärten', 'Nagel' → 'Nägel'.

Is there a way to modify my `$search` regex so that it would match the plural forms? 
Here's what I'm looking for:

```perl6
my $search_ä = $search.mymethod;
"ihre Väter" ~~ $search_ä;
say $/;  # ｢Väter｣
```

Of course, I can modify the `@words` array and 'precompile' it into a new `regex`. But it would be better (if possible) to modify the existing `regex` directly.

Comment: You should only optimize after getting it to a working state and after determining your code isn't fast enough.

Comment: @BradGilbert, what are possible drawbacks of using this optimization by default (in general, I work with hundreds of search keys and huge textual corpora, so without this optimization it's really slow)? Except for the code being less flexible and less elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

Regexes are code objects in Perl 6. So your question basically reads "Can I modify subroutines or methods after I've written them?". And the answer is the same for traditional code objects and for regexes: no, write them the you want them in the first place.

That said, you don't actually need `EVAL` for your use case. When you use an array variable inside a regex, it is interpolated as a list of alternative branches, so you could just write:

`my @words = <Vater Garten Nagel>;
my $search = /@words/;`

The regex `$search` becomes a closure, so if you modify `@words`, you also change what `$search` matches.

Another approach to this particular example would be to use the `:ignoremark` modifier, which makes `a` also match `ä` (though also lots of other forms, such as `ā` or `ǎ`.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! As for my using `EVAL` instead of `/@words/`, the problem is that with real data my `@words` search array usually contains several hundreds keys. So if I don't 'precompile' them with `EVAL`, the program becomes really slow. I've asked several questions about this problem, so if there is a better solution, please let me know. ① [Regex speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867216/regex-speed-in-perl-6) ② [Filtering an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933838/filtering-elements-of-an-array-with-elements-of-another-array-in-perl-6)