# Filtering an array with many keys of same length in Perl 6

Tags: raku

This question continues [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46933838/7730888) about filtering (the variable names are changed from `array` & `search` to `source` & `keys`).

Suppose there are even more elements and more keys. The program should print only those element of the `@source` which begin with any of `@keys`. So, `jjjjk` will be printed, but `jjjkk` won't.

Here's the most straightforward way to solve the problem, but it's too slow to be used:

```perl6
my @source = "aaaaa" .. "kkkkk";
my @keys = "aaaa" .. "jjjj";

.put for @source .grep: /^ @source /;

# produced 4 elements in 60 seconds
# out of 10 ** 4 * 11 = 110_000
# will take ~19 days to finish
```

Using `.Any` and `.starts-with()` makes it ~100x faster:

```perl6
my @source = "aaaaa" .. "kkkkk";
my @keys = "aaaa" .. "jjjj";
my $keys_any = @keys.any;

.put for @source .grep: *.starts-with($keys_any);

# produced 700 elements in 110 seconds
# will take ~4.5 hours
```

If we [pre-compile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869857/7730888) the regex, it works much (~15000x) faster:

```perl6
my @source = "aaaaa" .. "kkkkk";
my @keys = "aaaa" .. "jjjj";
my $keys = "/@keys.join('|')/".EVAL;

.put for @source .grep: /^ <$keys> /;

# produced all the elements in 100 seconds
```

Nevertheless, it's still too long, so I've decided to take advantage of the fact that all the keys are of the same length. So, I use a `Set` of `@keys` to check substrings of the same length of the `@source` array:

```perl6
my @source = "aaaaa" .. "kkkkk";
my @keys = "aaaa" .. "jjjj";
my $keys = @keys.Set;

for @source -> $str {
  my $substring = $str.substr(0, 4);
  if $substring (elem) $keys {
     put $str;
     next;
   }
}

# produced all the elements in 3 seconds
```

I feel though, that I'm reinventing the wheel and that there should be built-in instruments and methods to do such things?

Comment: What you want is called a "trie". It's a tree data structure where the top row represents the first letter of a word. The second row represents the second letter. And so on. To see if a word is in the trie, you look for the word's first letter in the top row. If you find it, you look for the next letter in the children of the letter you found. (And so on.) For your case, you would need to modify the end logic--you don't want a complete match, you just want to get to an "end" node (a node that represents the end of a `"aaaaa" .. "kkkkk"` word).

Comment: Unfortunately, tries are slow in perl and probably slower in Perl 6. There are some modules that provide tries, but to be fast enough, you would want to access the data using NQP functions, and I'm not even sure that would be enough. Maybe someone else can prove me wrong and point to a blazing fast trie implementation, but it would allow you to write a solution that doesn't become slower despite adding more words to the dictionary.

Comment: @piojo That's very, very interesting!! But could you please explain, why it will be faster than checking against a Set? Because in most cases (with those words that don't match) I won't have to compare all the 4 letters, but the check will end earlier? If so, in my case I'll have a theoretical 3-4x performance improvement, right? Or I misunderstand the whole idea of "trie"?

Comment: A trie can be bigger than a set. Whole languages can fit in a small trie, since it's a very efficient data structure. (That won't apply to Perl unless you store both the elements and the links from an element to its children in a more efficient way than the naive "one string (letter) per node, and a list of children per node". Tries work better in statically compiled languages.) Also, you won't have to limit yourself to words that are the same length.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is a bigger solution than you're looking for, really. You would need to read to the end of the data structure (downwards), but you wouldn't need to read to the end of the word. It's not more efficient than using sets, until you run out of memory for your set. (And it's useful if you realize you need to do prefix matching where the prefixes are different lengths.)

Comment: And what about non-prefix matching (middle or right part)? Good news about sets! Fortunately my keys aren't likely to be _so_ numerous. :)

Comment: Yeah, and there are totally different solutions for when your data set gets REALLY big, like bloom filters. As for general matching, "does word 'foo' contain any substring from my sample set?", you could do a separate trie search starting with each character in the word "foo", but that's not very imaginative. But the Rabin-Karp algorithm looks promising. I don't have time to read all about it now, but Wikipedia says it's used to search for many substrings within a string. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Comment: For Perl5 there is a module named Regexp::Assemble. Leveraging a similar approach might speed up your regex solution.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble

Comment: @piojo I've finally implemented a trie, and it does the matching of the data from this Q in 18 seconds. I would say, this is pretty fast, since the algorithm is not optimal in that there are useless transitions via the failure function (I don't feel fit to optimize it making a FSM, which precalculates the transitions for all the cases). The data in the trie is compressed from 40_000 letters to 11_101 vertices. My code is awful (choosing data structures to use was particularly hard), but it was a great challenge for me and a lot of fun. Thanks for mentioning the tries!

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Nice! I'm glad you enjoyed it, and frankly surprised it had a competitive speed. I used tries once in perl5, but now that I think further, memory usage was the problem rather than speed. And yes, how to store child nodes is a battle, and probably a compromise between speed and space. I would be sorely tempted to write a trie library in C++ (or download an open source trie library), then use NativeCall to interact with it. (Preferably, I would batch queries in case sending each query to NativeCall is slow.)

Comment: @piojo I think the speed is due to the fact that it's not an ordinary trie, but the trie from [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) algorithm (it was a surprise for me to learn that Aho stands for A in AWK). My main goal was to understand the principle of matching via tries to be able to use it when needed in future.

Answer (score 3):

> I feel though, that I'm reinventing the wheel and that there should be built-in instruments and methods to do such things?

There *are* built-in methods to do such things, as you have demonstrated yourself. They should "just" be optimized to the point where they are fast enough for your use cases.

If compiler optimizations are not your thing, you can contribute to the [Perl 6 Core Development Fund](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl_6_core_development_fund) to enable smart and dedicated people to work on it.

Comment: The only link 'make a donation' leads me to the page of [Perl Foundation](http://donate.perlfoundation.org/), but I'd rather prefer to make a donation specifically to the Perl 6 developers. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I believe you can make a donation through the general donate link, and then specify the target in a comment that you can enter. If there's a problem, please contact the Perl Foundation folk at http://www.perlfoundation.org/contact_us

Answer (score 1):

At present, I'll stick to the following solution, which uses the magic of `Sets` inside a regex, since it's more general than the one with `.substr` in my Q.

```perl6
my @source = "aaaaa" .. "kkkkk";
my @keys = "aaaa" .. "jjjj";
my $keys = @keys.Set;

for @source -> $str {
  $str ~~ m/ ^ ( . ** 4 ) <?{ ~$0 (elem) $keys }> /;
  put $str if so $/;
}

# produced all the elements in 11 seconds
```